# Multithreading / non-blocking

Tags: php, multithreading, nonblocking

Im running beanstalkd server to handle 'jobs'. I have a file called Worker.php that handles the jobs. Each job has a 'name' and a file to require. The Worker should start a new include of the required file; but I want to do that in a new process without interupting the parent, so more processes/requires can be done.

What is the best way to go here?

PThreads is not a option since I can't enable ZTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a process in the background:

```
exec("php Worker.php > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: Using exec() will interupt my parent process and will not let me know if the script has finished; or excited.

Comment: You can use `proc_open()`. You'll get more controll.